# Llamar a una función desde la propia función JAVA

Tags: java, funciones

Estaba desarrollando un menú muy sencillo con un Switch-Case y quería que si uno de los valores introducidos no es adecuado, el programa volviese a sacar el menú por pantalla para elegir. El código es el siguiente:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu {
public static void menuManagement(){
    try {
        String menu = "1 - Ver inventario \n2 - Buscar objeto \n3 - Anhadir objeto \n4 - Retirar objeto \n5 - Eliminar objeto \n6 - Salir \n\nIntroduzca la operacion deseada";
        System.out.println(menu);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String option = scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.close();
        switch (option) {
            case "1": //Ver inventario
                System.out.println(option);
                break;
            case "2": //Buscar objeto
                System.out.println(option);
                break;
            case "3": //Añadir objeto
                System.out.println(option);
                break;
            case "4": //Retirar objeto
                System.out.println(option);
                break;
            case "5": //Eliminar objeto
                System.out.println(option);
                break;
            case "6": //Salir
                System.out.println(option);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("El termino introducido es incorrecto");
                menuManagement();
                break;
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }    
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    menuManagement();
}
}
```

En el default hago una llamada a sí mismo, menuManagment pero si meto un valor fuera de los Case me arroja "No line found"

Alguna sugerencia?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: La verdad, no programo en Java hace un tiempo, pero si no me equivoco, deberías poder llamarlo con `Menu.menuManagement()`

Comment: ¿ Que significa `pero si meto un valor fuera de los Case me arroja "No line found"` ? Por favor, muestra un codigo **con error** y se te ayudará a corregirlo. Mostrar un código **que no tiene errores** no tiene sentido.

Comment: Intenta hacer lo mismo pero sin cerrar el scanner [ scanner.close () ] , creo que ahí está el error.

Comment: @Juanjo lo que quiero decir es que al introducir por consola de comandos un 7 (por ejemplo) que está fuera de lo contemplado por los Case (van del 1 al 6) por pantalla me sale ese error. Es decir, si por algún casual entramos en el default statement, salta el error.

Comment: @KBeDev ya he probado eso también, por si acaso, y me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: @LucasRox pues tienes razón, si no lo cierro el programa funciona sin problemas. Dejarlo abierto no dará problemas o solo es un warning y ya?

Comment: @AnxoDoTea el programa va a funcionar igual pero no es bueno dejarlo así  (por razones que no puedo explicar en un comentario ) además estas cerrando System.in y no lo vas a poder usar nuevamente por ejemplo en main o una segunda llamada al mismo método . Busca la forma de cerrarlo cuando termine todo el programa. Luego escribo una respuesta ahora 4:50 am zZzz .Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de un while, de esta forma siempre se cargaría el menú nuevamente y únicamente la opción "6" terminaría el bucle.

```
public static void menuManagement() {
    try {
        String menu = "1 - Ver inventario \n2 - Buscar objeto \n3 - Anhadir objeto \n4 - Retirar objeto \n5 - Eliminar objeto \n6 - Salir \n\nIntroduzca la operacion deseada";
        System.out.println(menu);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Varíable para terminar while.
        boolean exit = false;

        while (!exit) {

            String option = scanner.next();

            switch (option) {
                case "1": //Ver inventario
                    System.out.println(option);
                    break;
                case "2": //Buscar objeto
                    System.out.println(option);
                    break;
                case "3": //Añadir objeto
                    System.out.println(option);
                    break;
                case "4": //Retirar objeto
                    System.out.println(option);
                    break;
                case "5": //Eliminar objeto
                    System.out.println(option);
                    break;
                case "6": //Salir
                    System.out.println(option);
                    exit = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("El termino introducido es incorrecto");
                    //menuManagement();
                    break;
            }
        }

        scanner.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A mi me parece que planteas mal la cosa. Tal vez es mejor hacer algún tipo de comprobación sobre la variable 'opcion' y asegurarte que el valor introducido sea el esperado. Te ahorrarás el 'default' (y también el try). Por ejemplo, podrías hacer algo tipo (a falta de revisar el código):

```
    Matcher matcher;
    Pattern patternNumerico = Pattern.compile("[1-6]");
    String menu = "opciones...";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String option;
    do{
        System.out.println(menu);
        option = scanner.nextLine();
        matcher = patternNumerico.matcher(option);
    }while (!matcher.find());
    //aquí tu switch
```

..otra opción sería algo como:

```
      String menu = "opciones...";
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      String option;
      do {
        System.out.println(menu);
        option = scanner.charAt(0)
    } while (option >= 1 && option <= 6);
    //...aquí tu switch
```

Podrías poner esto en un método para que te hiciera la comprobación, en fin, siempre hay varias opciones.

Que me corrijan los que saben!